# creating module in python - how imports work

Tags: python, module

I'm creating a module in a python app, I have my primary code file, and I want to import some helper methods/classes from a helper folder. This is what I have for my folder structure:

```
module:
  __init__.py
  helpers:
    __init__.py
    some_class.py
```

this is `module/helpers/__init__.py` file:

```
  from .some_class import SomeClass

  def helper_method_1():
    # code

  def helper_method_2():
    # code
```

so my question is: is importing `SomeClass` inside `module/helpers/__init__.py` inside the `helpers` enough to use it as in import in my main `module/__init.py` file?

this is what I'm trying in my `module/__init__.py`

```
from .helpers import (SomeClass, helper_method_1, helper_method_2)
```

I'm kind of in the middle of doing a bunch of things, so can't test it for errors at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is enough.

Unless module has `__all__` variable, all names (including names imported from other modules) are exported.